# How does NextJS handle context if it is a singleton?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

From looking at React's source code, a new context appears to be a singleton object in the `current` nested child value in the global [Dispatcher object](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a1f97589fd298cd71f97339a230f016139c7382f/packages/react/src/ReactCurrentDispatcher.js).

- [createContext](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a1f97589fd298cd71f97339a230f016139c7382f/packages/react/src/ReactContext.js#L15)
- [useContext](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a1f97589fd298cd71f97339a230f016139c7382f/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L75)

So how in the world is it safe to use this on the server? How does NextJS or Remix prevent this global object from being leaked to other users? There could be secure information stored in a context object.